# DMM showing voltage when one lead is hanging in air

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement

My meter gives me a reading when I connect the positive lead to something and the com lead is just hanging there. Is this the voltage difference between the air and what ever my positive lead is touching?

Comment: What mode? AC? DC?  The voltage is not so much the air as it is the circuit at the analog-digital converter. Everything has some capacitance, resistance, and inductance so a variety of scenarios can cause what you observe. Meter could also just be going nuts.

Comment: This is normal for most DMMs. The leads pick up some electric fields around you.

Answer (score 1):

The probe doesn't need to be physically contacting anything to have a potential imposed upon it.

Anything which is changing in potential, or carrying current which is changing, produces magnetic and/or electric fields which influence the potential of conductors nearby, the probe in this case.

You're just seeing the potential of the probe (with respect to the other probe) which is capacitively and inductively coupled to those other sources in its vicinity, such as local mains wiring and your own body.

Comment: inductively coupled perhaps if the leads are shorted, not so sure it is a significant enough mechanism to be worth mentioning if the leads are open

Comment: It matters for a physics paper im working on if there is a reading then what ever the leads are touching is supplying the voltages that are being used to determine the potential difference? wouldn't that mean matter isnt electrically neutral?